# Python. Обращение к функции из функции

Tags: python, list

Есть класс, отвечающий за формирование доспехов персонажа.

```
from re import sub,UNICODE
global helment,armor,pants,boots

class hero_configuration:

    def show_heroes_stuff(self,hero_stuff_list,stuff):

        for names in hero_stuff_list:
            print(names[0])

        choose_stuff = int(input("Выбор: "))
        while( choose_stuff < 1 or choose_stuff > 6 ):
            choose_stuff = int(input("Ошибка! Выбор: "))

        stuff = sub(r"[^\w+]"," ",hero_stuff_list[choose_stuff-1][0],flags=UNICODE)
        print(stuff)


    #warrior / if hero_class == 1#
    def warrior_function(self):

        warrior_helment_list = [
        ("1 [ Стальной шлем славного рыцаря славного королества  ]",2,0),
        ("2 [ Древний древесный шлем из южных ведьменских лесов  ]",1,1),
        ("3 [ Проклятый стальной шлем из лесов тёмных ведьм      ]",2,2),
        ("4 [ Раскалённый шлем огненно-каменных земель Кронуса   ]",3,3),
        ("5 [ Зелёная, обтянутая сеткой каска с игральной картой ]",4,4),
        ("6 [ Золотой шлем самого сэра Марка Мак-Миллона         ]",4,5)
        ]

        helment = " "
        self.show_heroes_stuff(warrior_helment_list,helment)
        print("HELMENT IS "+helment)


    def __init__(self): #hero_create_done

        hero_class = int(input("press '1': "))
        if ( hero_class == 1 ):
            self.warrior_function()

hero_configuration();input()
```

При вызове **print(helment)** ничего не происходит

Comment: Надо бы исправить. Но есть соображения на счёт самой проблемы?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте отступы в классе

Comment: @soon с классом всё в порядке. Не работает переменная.

Comment: Если сейчас скопировать Ваш код, то он не будет работать. Пожалуйста, исправьте это, чтобы мы больше не отвлекались на подобные мелочи. Также, хотелось бы уточнить, о каком вызове `print` идет речь. О `print("HELMENT IS "+helment)`?

Comment: Да, он самый. Извинияюсь за предоставленные неудобства.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы передаете переменную `helment` в функцию, после чего ее изменяете внутри этой функции:

```
def show_heroes_stuff(self,hero_stuff_list,stuff):
    # ...
    stuff = sub(r"[^\w+]"," ",hero_stuff_list[choose_stuff-1][0],flags=UNICODE)

def warrior_function(self):
    # ...
    helment = " "
    self.show_heroes_stuff(warrior_helment_list,helment)
```

Изменение переменной внутри функции не влияет на переменную снаружи функции (в данном контексте). Самое простое, что Вы можете сделать - вернуть переменную из функции:

```
def show_heroes_stuff(self,hero_stuff_list,stuff):
    # ...
    stuff = sub(r"[^\w+]"," ",hero_stuff_list[choose_stuff-1][0],flags=UNICODE)
    print(stuff)
    return stuff

def warrior_function(self):
    # ...
    helment = " "
    helment = self.show_heroes_stuff(warrior_helment_list,helment)
    print("HELMENT IS "+helment)
```

Но я бы не советовал идти этим путем. Вместо этого я бы посоветовал Вам продумать архитектуру - выбирать экипировку из списка, а затем ее еще и парсить регулярками - однозначно плохое решение. Храните "чистое" описание, а при выводе добавляйте украшательства.

Comment: Да, спасибо. Я постараюсь переделать архитектуру игры.